# Tensorflow - semantic segmentation

Tags: matplotlib, neural-network, tensorflow

Posting here to check if there's anything wrong with my implementation of a simple semantic segmentation model in TensorFlow. This code represents a sanity check I'm doing with just a single image from the database, for which I'm trying to overfit the model. 
It is a binary classification problem with each image pixel mapped to [0,1] in the ground truth label.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = plt.imread('image.png') #Image of size [750,750,3]
img = plt.imread('map.png') # Ground Truth of size [750, 750]

img = np.expand_dims(img, 0)
lab = np.expand_dims(lab, 0)

w1 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.001, shape=[3,3,3,32]))
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=[32]))

w2 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.001, shape=[3,3,32,2]))
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=[2]))

mul = tf.nn.conv2d(img, w1, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding='SAME')
bias_add = tf.add(mul, b1)
conv1 = tf.nn.relu(bias_add)

mul2 = tf.nn.conv2d(conv1, w2, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding='SAME')
bias_add2 = tf.add(mul2, b2)
conv2 = tf.nn.relu(bias_add2)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

lab = lab.astype('int32')

conv2_out = tf.reshape(conv2, [-1, 2])
lab = np.reshape(lab, [-1])

prediction = tf.nn.softmax(pred) # I use this to visualize prediction of the model, and calculate accuracy

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(conv2_out, lab))

optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001).minimize(loss)

correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), lab)
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)

tf.initialize_all_variables().run()

step = 1 
iter = 5

while step < iter:
    sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: img, y: lab})
    loss_val,acc = sess.run([loss,accuracy], feed_dict={x: img, y: lab})
    print ("Iter:"+ str(step) +" Loss : " + "{:.6f}".format(loss_val)#+ " Accuracy : " + "{:.6f}".format(acc))
    step += 1

print ("optimization finished!")

prediction_logits = prediction.eval()
weights = w1.eval() # first layer learned weights

prediction_logits = np.reshape(prediction_logits, [750,750,2])

plt.figure() # Plotting original image with predicted labels
plt.imshow(img[0,:,:,:])
plt.imshow(prediction_logits[:,:,0], cmap=plt.cm.binary)
plt.show()

plt.figure() # Plotting first layer weights
for i in range(32):
    plt.subplot(8,4,i+1)
    plt.imshow(weights[:,:,:,i])
plt.show()
```

When I run this (as an interactive session), just to train the model to overfit on this single image, the loss minimizes, but my accuracy doesn't seem to change. I'm not quite sure I understand how the `tf.argmax` function works or if I've implemented it correctly - and the accuracy sticks to a single value no matter how many iterations.

Thoughts? Also, am I going about plotting the figure and predicted label correctly, or are there any errors here? (any other errors as well - or best practices I'm not following, do point them out)

Additionally, what is the recommended way to implement a regularization over the weights? I found [`tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/contrib.layers.html#l2_regularizer) to be a feasible option - how do I include it in this scenario, though? A simple sum with the loss function?

Comment: In this line `prediction = tf.nn.softmax(pred) # I use this to visualize prediction of the model, and calculate accuracy`. What is 'pred'?